# Approximate eigenvectors for a set of non-commuting self-adjoint operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, sp.spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

This problem is motivated by finding the right mathematical setting for expressing the compatibility of classical physics with quantum mechanics.

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert space and $S$ a bounded self-adjoint operator. Then define $x \in \mathcal H$ to be an $\epsilon$-approximate eignevector if $\|Sx-\lambda x\| < \epsilon.\|x\|$ where $\lambda = \langle Sx,x\rangle /\|x\|^2$. Given a finite set of bounded self-adjoint operators $S_1,\cdots,S_n$ and bounds $\vec\epsilon = (\epsilon_1,\cdots,\epsilon_n)$, we say $S_1,\cdots,S_n$ are $\vec\epsilon$-classical if $\mathcal H$ is spanned by elements $x \in \mathcal H$ that are $\epsilon_i$-approximate eigenvectors of $S_i$ *for all $i$*.

A simple example is $\mathcal H = L^2(\mathbb R)$, $T_1 =$ mult by $x$, $T_2 = i\cdot d/dx$, $S_1 = \tau_{c_1}(T_1), S_2 = \tau_{C_2}(T_2)$ where $\tau_C(x) = \max(\min(x,C),-C)$ is a cutoff function (n.b. no measuring instrument can register unbounded values). Then $x_{a,b} = e^{iax}\cdot e^{(x-b)^2/2\sigma^2}$ are the best candidates for approximate eigenvectors of $S_1$ and $S_2$.

The question is to find natural bounds on the commutators $[S_i,S_j]$ that imply $S_1,\cdots,S_n$ are $\vec\epsilon$-classical with $\vec\epsilon$ a function of $\|S_i\|$ and the bounds on $[S_i,S_j]$. I have such results using the Hilbert-Schmidt norms of the commutators but the resulting $\vec\epsilon$ seem much too big. I seek ideas or references for work in this direction.

Comment: Welcome to Mathoverflow

Comment: Very good question. Are you sure, though, that the assumption on your $\epsilon$-approximate eigenvalue (if I may call it like that) $\lambda$ to be of the form $\lambda = \langle Sx,x\rangle / \|x\|^2$ isn't a bit too restrictive?. For instance, the lowest spectral value of $S$ can never be of this form unless it is an eigenvalue of $S$. As every spectral value of a self-adjoint operator is an approximate eigenvalue, this shows that the set of $\epsilon$-approximate eigenvalues does not contain the set of approximate eigenvalues, in general.

Comment: Did you consider coherent states of irreducible SU(2)-representations ?

Comment: "if $H$ is spanned by elements $x\in H$ that are $\varepsilon_i$-approximate eigenvectors of $S_i$ for all $i$." I'm not sure you want just that little: if $x$ is a common approximate eigenvector, then a whole neighborhood of $x$ consists of approximate eigenvectors, so the spanning property becomes pretty much void.

Comment: Good point. I want to say that, if you start in any state $x$, then by a classical measurement, you project ("collapse" in Copenhagen language) that state into an approximate eigenstate of all $S_i$. For one $S$, the state is an integral of its projections into eigenstates and its norm squared is the integral of the squared norms of the projections. I want something like that but yes, this needs to be thought through.

Comment: @DavidMumford: If that (your last comment) was the idea, then I'm not sure why the notion of approximate eigenvectors was necessary at all. The more precise version would be that if you observe a value of the observable $S$ in $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ and your system was in state $\psi\in\mathcal H$, then the state must be updated ("collapsed" but that is awful terminology and has fooled many people into thinking that something mysterious is going on) to $E(A)\psi$, with $E$ denoting the spectral resolution of $S$.

Comment: The problem is that $S_i$ don't commute, there are $n$ different things to measure and one can't get an exact value for all of them. To restate what I want, I suppose I am asking that one can choose a countable set of $\epsilon$-approximate eigenstates that forms a frame with upper and lower bounds not to far apart,like the wavelets in the example I gave.

Comment: I can only reiterate my point (which may well be beside the point), if the approximate eigenfunctions are supposed to model collapse of the wave function, that's simply not how it works. If the operators don't commute, then you can't measure them simultaneously, and if you measure them one after the other, then the state gets updated by successive spectral projections, as in my previous comment.

Comment: Sure, that's the standard model. But my point is that it doesn't accurately model our experience as macroscopic creatures moving around in a world that, to within limits, is wholly classical. We observe position and momentum simultaneously of many day to day objects, but we do it  _approximately_. I seek a natural mathematical model of that, seeking what the bounds are for a classical world.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you a few papers, and these have references to others.  I discuss joint approximate eigenvectors in the context of approximate joint measurement in [1].  You need to know that often it is $K$-theory that tells you if such a basis can be found or not.  In [2] is a section called ``joint Wannnier spread'' that seems to be what you are after.  It dicusses the distinction between Hilbert Schmidt errors and operator norm errors. I learned of this line of reasoning from Hastings, who discusses the case of 2 observables.  All this work is on finite dimensional Hilbert space, but the joint pseudospectrum I discuss in [1] can work in infinite dimensions.

[1] Loring, Terry A. "K-theory and pseudospectra for topological insulators." Annals of Physics 356 (2015): 383-416.

[2] Loring, Terry A., and Adam P. W. Sørensen. "Almost commuting unitary matrices related to time reversal." Communications in Mathematical Physics 323.3 (2013): 859-887.

[3] Hastings, M. B. "Topology and phases in fermionic systems." Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment 2008.01 (2008): L01001.